# How to fix: Err:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, google-chrome

I'm trying to 'sudo apt update' my system, but suddenly I got the following error, I looked for a solution on other communities and forums so I found 2 files where I might a solution so I took a look on "/etc/apt/sources.list" and "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list" and tried to un/comment un/necessary sources but I didn't figured out how to what to do exactly, Please help me!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

Open the 'Software & Updates' program. Under Other Software look for the repository. It should be called something like 'Google Chrome Stable.'

Click on that repository and click remove. Then, just reinstall Google Chrome and the repository should be reinstalled with the correct configuration.

EDIT:
You can do this by typing the following commands:

```
$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

# sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Hi @Jaco Malan, now it's mysql with same issue: 
€rr:8 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease